# Correct numeric field behavior when deleting characters?

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic

Suppose I have a numeric field in an edit box, with a valid range of 2.0 - 13.0. The field is bound to a numeric value `V` in my program, as is a slider, so changes in the field will update `V` and the slider position, and changes in the slider position will update `V` and the numeric field content.

What should be the behavior of the field content when a user presses the Backspace key in these situations?

```
2.03
2.0
2.
2
???? what should the field contain
```

and

```
10.7
10.
10
???? what should the field contain
```

The unvalidated field content of (blank) and `1` are not valid. Should the field correct its content to lie within the valid range? Should it allow text content to be invalid but somehow indicate that invalid-ness?

Answer (score 1):

The text content should be marked as invalid. The slider should remain at the latest valid position. This would be the least surprising behaviour.

A text field correcting its content would most probably confuse the user.